# Are the datetime package and the memoir class known to conflict?

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, datetime

Using the `\formatdate` macro from the `datetime` package within a `\date` definition seems to break when using the `memoir` class.  Is this just something strange that I'm doing because it seems reasonable.  A minimal example of this is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{datetime}
\title{Dummy}
\date{\formatdate{1}{1}{2001}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

causes pdflatex to complain saying:

```
Package fmtcount Warning: \ordinal already defined use \FCordinal instead. on input line 430.

(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fc-english.def))))
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 4.
```

I'm obviously doing something more complicated in reality and can work around this bug, but it's a bit unexpected!

Comment: Use the `silence` package for avoiding the warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to protect `\formatdate`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{datetime}
\title{Dummy}
\date{\protect\formatdate{1}{1}{2001}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanks!  never had anything that's required a `\protect` before, they should occur to me now...