# Memoir class conflict with datetime

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, datetime, fmtcount

Hi I'm running into a warning when trying to call the `datetime` package within a document using the `memoir` class. MWE is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
Package fmtcount Warning: \ordinal already defined use \FCordinal instead. on input line 450.
```

The conflict between `fmtcount` and `memoir` is well documented and the solution is, as suggested, to use `\FCordinal` in place of `\ordinal`. The problem I have is I am not calling `\ordinal`. It must be occurring within the `datetime` file (or similar). Can anyone advise how to address this.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78138/are-the-datetime-package-and-the-memoir-class-known-to-conflict

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime) [change log](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/CHANGES), version 2.41 of `datetime` has [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) split out as a separate package:

> New to version 2.41: Package has been split into two 
>   files: `datetime.sty` and `fmtcount.sty`.  The latter file 
>   contains the definitions for all the macros that display 
>   the value of a counter (e.g. `\ordinal`, `\octal`).
>   Extra macro `\decimal` added (like `\arabic`, but can pad it 
>   with leading zeroes.)

So, when you load `datetime`, it loads `fmtcount`, which identifies the "conflict". The following is taken from [`fmtcount.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount/fmtcount.dtx):

```
2660:  \@ifundefined{ordinal}
2661:   {\let\ordinal\FCordinal}%
2662:   {%
2663:     \PackageWarning{fmtcount}%
2664:     {\string\ordinal \space already defined use 
2665:      \string\FCordinal \space instead.}
2666:   }
```

Prior to the above conditional, `\FCordinal` is defined and substituted *if* `\ordinal` doesn't already exist.

Note that this is only a warning, and the suggestion is to use `\FCordinal` rather than `\ordinal`. So, if that's a possibility, it should not be a problem.

Comment: The issue I have is I do not know where \ordinal is being called to  replace with \FCordinal and I do hate having errors ever so much

Comment: (1) `\ordinal` is defined conditionally in [`fmtcount.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount/fmtcount.dtx) (see lines 2660-2666). It checks whether it already exists or not, and either overwrites it with `\FCordinal` or not (printing a *warning*; not an *error*). (2) If you want to avoid this *warning* in your `.log`, add `\let\ordinal\relax` before loading `\usepackage{datetime}`.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @TomBrien: Note that use `\let\ordinal\relax` might cause problems (not tested) with [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) if they don't use the same interface/restrictions-of-use...